# un-explainable problem with file uploads

Tags: php, codeigniter, upload

Everything was  fine with my file upload script until I decided to upload larger files and by larger files am talking about just `2mb` talk more of a `30mb` file. I have been to my `php.ini` to change the following:

```
post_max_size = 100M
upload_max_filesize = 120M
```

The memory limit was left `@` d default `128M` 
after all this settings it still did not work, it shows this error message

```
"file could not be written to disk"
```

Some friends suggested that it had something to do with d permissions but I doubt that because the same script works for smaller files 600kb and below. I can't really explain what is going on. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you restart your httpd server after modifying the configuration values?

Comment: Also, check the current ini settings with `phpinfo()`. And check that you have enough space on disk!

Comment: Could you tell us what o/s you're running on?

Comment: This is most likely a memory / quota issue.

Comment: With some languages / frameworks, different uploads are handled in different ways - small uploads are sent directly to memory, large ones are written to disc. Perhaps it's just treating the larger files differently?

Answer (score 2):

If linux, check your quota for the user.
Maybe your disk is full.

Comment: @Pekka @GaryBarnett @Ajweb @Epharion am running on windows 7 with more than enough space on my hard disk.....

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and fixed it by increasing the size of the tmp folder. Check the tmp folder size and make the size is big enough.